# When I use vim on my own computer all text is the same color even when I use a python file

Tags: python, vim

How would I fix this?  I dont really know how to access the settings or even if I did how to change them.  Sorry for the stupid question it is just driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open your `.vimrc` file, and add this line:

```
:syntax on
```

---

If you don't know where your `.vimrc` file is located, you can type in your command line:

```
vim --version
```

You should have some like:

```
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

which tells you the location of the `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:set syntax=python` to see if there is any syntax highlighting.